# Replace Woocommerce reviews comments template with default comments template?

Tags: woocommerce, comments, review

How to remove the comments template that woocommerce uses for reviews and instead default to use site comments template?

I have edited single-product-reviews.php to adapt it to site's comments template and used woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args to adapt the form but just thought why not just use the custom comments template I already have.

edit:Have reached a successful way of doing this but don't think its the best

```
add_action('init', 'mdlr_disable_reviews');
function mdlr_disable_reviews() {
remove_filter( 'comments_template', array( WC_Template_Loader::init(),'comments_template_loader' ) );
add_filter( 'comments_template', array( WC_Template_Loader::init(),'mdlr_new_product_comments' )); //need this?
}
```

//then to disable reviews/comments under tabs

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'mdlr_remove_reviews_tab');
function mdlr_remove_reviews_tab( $tabs ) {
unset( $tabs[ 'reviews' ] );
 return $tabs;
}
```

//then i moved the reviews/comments

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','mdlr_new_product_comments');
 function mdlr_new_product_comments() {
 if ( ! comments_open() ) {
 return;
 }
 comments_template();
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add_filter with more priority as below:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', function() { return '/comments.php'; }, 30 );
```